# PHP Laravel framework installation in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, web-applications, laravel-4

I am trying to install [laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/quick) php framework. I have followed official [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/quick) and tried both of methods described there.

laravel folder appears in `/var/www/` after installation but when I navigate in browser to `http://localhost/laravel` it just displays me the contents of `laravel` folder.

I tried to change permissions, even I have tried to change the permissions of `/var/www/laravel/` to **777**. it did not work.

Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

"localhost/laravel/public" if it's not working

> chmod -R 777 /var/www/laravel/app/storage

then it will work.